# rails + jquery comfirming delete then calling delete method

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm working with Rails and jquery. I have a link..

```
<%= link_to 'Delete Meeting', "/meetings/#{@meeting.id}", {:class => "delete_meeting"}, :method => :delete %>
```

The above link is in my meetings show page. The behavior i'm looking for is that when a user clicks on the delete link, I want it to delete the meeting and then redirect to the meetings/index page where the remaining meetings are listed. I also want to display a "Your meeting has been deleted notice" on the index page.

When the user clicks on the above link, I ask for confirmation after which I want to simply call the delete method in the meetings controller. I don't want to use AJAX though, since after deletion I want to be routed to the meetings_path. For all this I have the following jquery..

```
$(".delete_meeting").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  jConfirm('Are you sure you want to delete this meeting?', 'Confirm Delete', function(r) {
    if(r){
        // what does here? I want to call the link's href here
    }
    return false;
  });
})
```

..If the confirm returns true then I want to send the request to the controller's delete action. How can i achieve this? I don't think i should be using a window.location.href for this. Do I?

Comment: Why are you using any extra javascript at all? Setting the `:method` parameter to `:delete` should be enough for the unobtrusive javascript to convert your regular browser request to one that Rails will identify as a DELETE, so it will get routed to the destroy method of your controller.

Comment: I edited my question to be more specific. Was not sure what extra javascript you were referring to.

Comment: This might help you: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js#L103 Apparently you can override the custom confirmation dialog presented by ujs.

Answer (score 0):

delete your jquery function, and add "redirect_to meetings_path" in destroy action

Comment: I want the user to confirm the delete action. Also, i don't want to use the standard onClick: confirm("are you sure?"). I'm using a jquery plugin for showing alerts and confirmations.